# Sending data through socket spaces, receiving with spaces

Tags: html, c++, qt, sockets, large-data

I'm using C++ with QT4 for this. And when I try to send large html files(in this case, 8kb), the process of sending and receiving work well. But the file received come with spaces between each character of the html file. Here an example,
the file is sent like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta name="qrichtext" content="1" /><style type="text/css">
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
</style></head><body style=" font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
<p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">a</p></body></html>
```

and it's received, like this:

```
  ¼ < ! D O C T Y P E   H T M L   P U B L I C   " - / / W 3 C / / D T D   H T M L   4 . 0 / / E N "   " h t t p : / / w w w . w 3 . o r g / T R / R E C - h t m l 4 0 / s t r i c t . d t d " > 
 < h t m l > < h e a d > < m e t a   n a m e = " q r i c h t e x t "   c o n t e n t = " 1 "   / > < s t y l e   t y p e = " t e x t / c s s " > 
 p ,   l i   {   w h i t e - s p a c e :   p r e - w r a p ;   } 
 < / s t y l e > < / h e a d > < b o d y   s t y l e = "   f o n t - f a m i l y : ' M S   S h e l l   D l g   2 ' ;   f o n t - s i z e : 8 . 2 5 p t ;   f o n t - w e i g h t : 4 0 0 ;   f o n t - s t y l e : n o r m a l ; " > 
 < p   s t y l e = " - q t - p a r a g r a p h - t y p e : e m p t y ;   m a r g i n - t o p : 0 p x ;   m a r g i n - b o t t o m : 0 p x ;   m a r g i n - l e f t : 0 p x ;   m a r g i n - r i g h t : 0 p x ;   - q t - b l o c k - i n d e n t : 0 ;   t e x t - i n d e n t : 0 p x ; " > < / p > < / b o d y > < / h t m l >
```

the code i'm using for sending and receiving:

Sending code:
    qDebug() << "Connected. Sending file to the server";
    QString text = ui->QuestHtmlText->toPlainText();

```
if(text.length() < 1024)
{
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << quint16(0) << QUESTION_HTML;
    out << text;
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << quint16(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    qDebug() << "Block size: " << block.size();
    socket.write(block);
    return;
}

for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i+=1024)
{
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << quint16(0) << QUESTION_HTML;
    if((text.length() - i) > 1024)
        out << text.mid(i, i+1024);
    else
        out << text.right(1024 - i);
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << quint16(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    qDebug() << "Block size: " << block.size();
    socket.write(block);
}
```

Receiving code:

```
qDebug() << "Writing File";
QDataStream in(this);
QString temp = "Teste.html", text;
QFile myFile(".//Questions//" + temp);
myFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&myFile);
while(!in.atEnd())
{
    in >> text;
    out << text;
}
```

Comment: I bet there are not spaces between characters (but 0s) & it's related to your use of `quint16`.

Comment: +1 to @EugenConstantinDinca. And the extra gibberish at the start is probably an attempt to render a UTF-16 BOM as a character.

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca make it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem writing it to a file and getting this file to a QByteArray, and sending the QbyteArray entirely to the socket.

Answer (score 3):

@Eugen i suspect the quint16 is either not written at all or is at the end of the file. Read below.

@Patrick [don't repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971872/receiving-data-with-spaces-thru-sockets) only because you feel like not being served fast enough. Stackowerflow is not a hotline.

The stuff you are getting back in the file is not your original text, but QString serialization form, which is unsuprisingly UTF-16. If you want your text back, read the input QDataStream back to QString and save that into file.

While prefixing your data with a length is generally a good idea, it is absolutely redundant with QString >> QDataStream. Read up something [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html) or [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_perform_file_IO_using_QDataStream_in_Qt). Moreover you have developed a mind boggingly obfuscated way which i suspect is doing nothing. QByteArray is not implementing QIODevice (indeed, why it should) so your out.device()->seek() is a base virtual implementation, [empty and just returning true](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#seek). I won't be surprised if your length "header" is found at the end of your serialization dump file.

**Edit:** i think that your html transport might start working correctly only by leaving out the confused quint operation completely and use `out` QTextStream instead of QByteStream.

Comment: I think the quint(0) is confusing the QString decoder on the client side since it will not see the BOM first.

Comment: I still think that the quint operation does not have direct influence on what @Patrick gets in the file. Yes he reads QString from his `in` stream (i admit not being completely clear about that in my post) but then he again writes it to `out` QDataStream backed directly by QFile. So again the same case of serialization.

Comment: Guys, i'm so sorry i didnt mention this before. But this quint(0) is read in some point earlier in the code. So, I guess this isnt the thing here. Cause the QByteArray pointer is pointing to somewhere after the quint(0) which makes the QString not read it. Am i wrong?

Comment: Read my answer again and visit at least the first link i have provided. You will learn that QString written to QDataStream is serialized as the string length in bytes (quint32) followed by the data in UTF-16. Because you are writing the QDataStream serialization directly to file, this is exactly what you get in the file.

Comment: @vtmarvin yeah, guess you're right. I'll try it here, and post the results.

Comment: @vtmarvin man, i can't leave out the quint(0) since the whole communicating structure of the program depends on it.

Comment: Man, just change QByteStream to QTextStream in your Receiving code. It works for me. If you are still getting gibberish at the beginning of your file, then you MUST leave out the quint, no matter your whole communicating structure.

Answer (score 2):

I bet there are not spaces between characters (but 0s) & you get the extra chars due to your use of `quint16`.

Comment: Is that the reason I get various NULL's when I open the html with de notepad++ ? Cause windows' notepad doesnt show the same thing. But I was wondering if was that, I'd get NULL between each character of the file, but the only thing I see is NULL's and no characters(just at maximum 10 characters). Anyway, the solution is change it to something like... char?

Comment: don't you think if was 0's it would between every 1024 amount of characters?